# I have a question about 'the change of variables technique'

Tags: random-variables

I am studying 'change of variable for random vairables' reading your lecture 4 slides, [The University of Leicester:EC2019 Sampling and Inference](http://www.le.ac.uk/users/dsgp1/COURSES/LEISTATS/Lecture4.pdf).

I could understand 'the change of variables technique' for random variables
thanks to the slides which is much more detailed than others.
I cannot, however, understand an formula in the bottom of page 3.
Why does the absolute value symbol disappear?

> Expectation of a function of random variable.
>   Let y=y(x) be a function of x∼f(x). The value of E(y) can be found without first determining the p.d.f g(y) of y. Quite simply, there is
>   $E(y)= \int_{x} y(x) f(x) dx $.
>   If y=y(x) is a monotonic transformation of x, then it follows that
>   $E(y)= \int_{y} yg(y) dy = \int_{y} y f\{x(y)\} | \frac{dx}{dy}| dy = \int_{x} y(x)f(x)dx $ which establishes a special case of the result.

Comment: I would say it's the determinant of the Jacobian !

Comment: Thank you, Romain! Why did not I think that was the determinant of the Jacobian? 
Thanks again.